# 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5338 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true. And this is my Code given Below

Tags: flutter, exception, navigator

When i implement code for Splash screen page and that navigate to a login screen and rising an EXception Like this 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5338 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true. the function i declared for navigating the page is not working properly but there is no compile time error, the error is only showing while run time. I don't Know how to this Solve this Pls Anybody help

```
import 'package:first_project_1/Screens/login.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenSplash extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenSplash({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScreenSplashState createState() => _ScreenSplashState();
}

class _ScreenSplashState extends State<ScreenSplash> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    gotoLogin(context);
  }
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/VDlogo.png',height: 150,),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }
  Future<void> gotoLogin(BuildContext context) async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4),);
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx)=> ScreenLogin(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Navigator.pushReplacement` is called right in the `initState`. Your `Future.delayed` isn't `await`ed, so it doesn't wait those 4 seconds for the push.

Comment: Can you tell me what change did I Make to solve this error

Comment: @VizzyDigitalDeals add `await` before `Future.delayed`